# An ()-time algorithm is NOT always faster than an (2)-time algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

> An ()-time algorithm is NOT always faster than an (^2)-time algorithm.

This statement is true. Anyone know what's the special case?

Comment: Remember that ()-notion describes *worst case*.

Comment: Is this a big omicron or omicron? And is this n^2 or n*2? Other than that, this question does not make that much sense. There is no single "special" case. n=0 or n=1 and we are done for example. And there are infinitely more cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just by the definition of O any algorithm in Θ(logn) is also in O(n^2) and is asymptotically faster than an algorithm in Θ(n).

Answer (score 4):

When the constant overhead of the `O(n)` algorithm is larger than n^2, which happens for small `n`.